# Trying to install ggpattern in a docker with R throws error

Tags: r, linux, docker

I have a docker that is made from Rails, but that docker needs to have install some R dependencies, and when I run  `install.packages(c('ggpattern', 'ggpubr'), dependencies = TRUE)`

it throws the following error

```
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'tidyr'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/tidyr'
ERROR: dependencies 'pbkrtest', 'lme4' are not available for package 'car'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/car'
ERROR: dependency 'gridpattern' is not available for package 'ggpattern'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ggpattern'
ERROR: dependency 'car' is not available for package 'rstatix'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rstatix'
ERROR: dependencies 'ggrepel', 'rstatix' are not available for package 'ggpubr'
* removing '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/ggpubr'
```

the docker uses ruby:2.5.1 image and installs R like this

```
RUN add-apt-repository "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian bullseye-cran40/"

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install r-base r-base-core r-recommended
```

I've tried installing without dependencies and with dependencies. I need to know if some one have done that and how to do that

Comment: There should be a more detailed error message about exactly what went wrong. Have you truncated the output? You are very likely missing system dependencies for those R packages or their dependencies.